# Can't record super simple macros on my workplace computer

Tags: vba

This should be a super simple macro, but it just doesn't record properly.
I just wanna record a macro every time I run it, it inputs number 222 in the activecell.

When I do record this macro on my own laptop,it is recorded as below:

`Sub Macro8()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "222"
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub`

Macro9 does not work and return me a error

But when I do the exact same thing on my workplace computer, it is recorded as below:

```
Sub Macro9()
    . = "222"
    Range("A1").ErrorString
End Sub
```

Never see this before, tried many ways to solve this but failed. Someone has an idea of what is going on? Thanks a ton in advance!

[image: this is the screen shot]

===========================================================================
I found a better way to describe this problem, wish this could help you guys understand what I am saying better!
In my own laptop, when I select Cell-A1, VB editor shows:

```
Range("A1").Select
```

On my workplace computer, when I select Cell-A1, VB editor shows:

```
Range("A1").ErrorString
```

Comment: It is somehow interesting to see that error kind of has something to do with cell "J9".Any idea why? Is it always the same? On your screenshot, your other documents are opened. What happen if you close them? Can it be an interfering maccro?

Comment: This is strange. Most feasible and sensible solution is to get your Excel re-installed.

Comment: "A1" or "J9" is not a problem, the main focus here is this Macro recorder does not give me any object before ".", and this made the value 222 with no place to store, this is really weird. I have worked with some complicated VB task before, never saw this problem

Comment: Thank for the reply guys, I close all the other documents except for the one I use, still it does not help,if I got the answer by myself or from other persons I will let you know why this problem happen and how to solve it!

Comment: What version of Office/Excel are you using? Is it the same on both machines?

Comment: Both excel 2016

Comment: I think this came up in a question last week where the computer in question was a new one. A re-install was the answer.  @ashleedawg - that ring any bells?

Comment: Oh yeah man! my workplace is using a brand new computer and we will do this today, hope it will work and I will feed you back if it really works @QHarr

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is to re-install excel! All other ways failed,thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question asked on an MS Forum https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Excel-Macro-Recording-Generate-Wrong-VBA/td-p/190857

The user fixed the issue by re-installing Office. That would be the surest way to fix the issue, but you could just try a repair first as it might work and would be quicker.

FWIW, I've used Excel macros for over 20 years and have never seen this problem.

Comment: Thanks Bro, I think the best way is to re-install Excel and I will try that

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is to re-install excel! All other ways failed, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct this situation by turning off "AutoSave". This resolved two things for me:

- The errors when attempting to Record a Marco
- Situations where my macros aborted for no apparent reason shutting down Excel

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this problem is to re-install excel! All other ways failed.
Thanks to the guys who answered my questions and have a nice day!